# jQuery Passing Contents of a Variable into a Selector

Tags: jquery, variables

I am a bit of a jQuery noob, but I cannot find the answer to a very basic question!

I am trying to create a system where a user can click on a word in a list, jQuery then gets the contents of that list item, adds it into a variable and then in my demo adds a background color to any items in another list where it finds that word.

The code seems to be creating the variable alright and the contents of the variable is correct, but I can't get it to use the contents of the variable in a :contains(variable) part of my selector. If I add a word in manually, such as aluminium it seems to work fine.

I'm sure this is just my inexperience with using the language but have been trawling through Google for days finding massively complex systems, but no basics such as this.

You can see from the below that I am using alert(test) to check the variable contains the correct string, then I'm trying to pass that string into the :contains(test) or (#test) so it will search for an highlight the lines in table.selection-items that include this string.

Any ideas would be great. Sorry it's such a noob question!

Thank
Simon

HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="config-test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.highlight {
    color: #F00;
}
.selection-itemsdiv {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<p class="no-script">For the selection guide to work you must have javascript enabled</p>

<ol class="selection-criteria">
    <li>Is this for a hazardous location? For example ex d rated enclosures?
        <ol class="hazardous">
            <li>Yes</li>
            <li>No</li>
        </ol>
    </li>


    <li>Materials
        <ol class="material">
            <li>Plastic</li>
            <li>Steel</li>
            <li>Aluminium</li>
            <li>Stainless Steel</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>IP Rating
        <ol class="iprating">
            <li>IP55</li>
            <li>IP56</li>
            <li>IP65</li>
            <li>IP66</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>

<table class="selection-items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td>Range</td>
            <td>Hazardous Location</td>
            <td>Material</td>
            <td>IP Rating</td>
            <td>Smallest Size</td>
            <td>Biggest Size</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="image">Image</td>
            <td class="range">Universal NI (Steel)</td>
            <td class="hazardous">No</td>
            <td class="material">Steel</td>
            <td class="iprating">IP66</td>
            <td class="smlsize">300x200x150</td>
            <td class="lrgsize">1200x800x300</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="image">Image</td>
                <td class="range">Monarch IP (Stainless)</td>
                <td class="hazardous">No</td>
                <td class="material">Stainless Steel</td>
                <td class="iprating">IP66</td>
                <td class="smlsize">300x200x175</td>
                <td class="lrgsize">2000x800x600</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="image">Image</td>
                <td class="range">Monarch IP (Aluminium)</td>
                <td class="hazardous">No</td>
                <td class="material">Aluminium</td>
                <td class="iprating">IP66</td>
                <td class="smlsize">407x407x272</td>
                <td class="lrgsize">2007x807x602</td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td class="image">Image</td>
                <td class="range">Connector TE (Steel)</td>
                <td class="hazardous">No</td>
                <td class="material">Steel</td>
                <td class="iprating">IP66</td>
                <td class="smlsize">150x150x80</td>
                <td class="lrgsize">600x200x120</td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td class="image">Image</td>
                <td class="range">Connector TE (Steel)</td>
                <td class="hazardous">No</td>
                <td class="material">Stainless Steel</td>
                <td class="iprating">IP66</td>
                <td class="smlsize">150x150x80</td>
                <td class="lrgsize">600x200x120</td>
            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td class="image">Image</td>
                <td class="range">Exe Sloping Roof Terminal Box</td>
                <td class="hazardous">Yes</td>
                <td class="material">Stainless Steel</td>
                <td class="iprating">IP66</td>
                <td class="smlsize">300x200x150</td>
                <td class="lrgsize">1200x800x300</td>
            </tr>   

    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="selection-itemsdiv">
<h3>Connector TE</h3>
<p>No</p>
<p>Stainless Steel</p>
<p>IP66</p>
<p>300x200x150</p>
<p>1200x800x300</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// This removes the Script warning on the page
    $('p.no-script').remove();


$('ol.selection-criteria ol li').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('highlight');

    if($('ol.selection-criteria ol li').hasClass('highlight')) {
        var test = $(this).html();
        alert(test);
        $('table.selection-items tbody tr:contains(#test)').css('background-color','#dddddd')
    }
    else {
    }


});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table.selection-items tbody tr').contains(test).css('background-color','#dddddd')
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I must be getting the syntax wrong somewhere. I'm still not getting the table.selection-items lines to highlight though. Any ideas?

Comment: Hooray!!! Fixed it! The line needs to be: - $("table.selection-items tbody tr:contains('" + test + "')").css('background-color','#dddddd'); See the comments at the bottom of [link]http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/[/link]